# Build valid json object in Twig

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig

So I'm trying to build a JSON object in a Twig template and ran into some issues.
Responding to a POST request with something like this from a Twig works fine:

```
{"urls": ["/a","/b"]}
```

However if there's invalid json for example a trailing comma, like this;

```
{"urls": ["/a","/b",,,,,]}
```

then javascript complains when it receives it (which makes sense as it's invalid).

Doing something like this will always result in invalid JSON because of the trailing comma:

```
{"urls": [
{% for i in objects %}
    "/img/example/'~i.get_url()",
{% endfor %}
]}
```

**Question:**

So how do you use Twig to loop over an array of objects and build a valid JSON object?

Comment: A templating language isn't really suited to creating complex objects. This is something you should be solving in PHP.

Comment: Don't go this way. Templates should DISPLAY only and not contain any logic. I know it's tempting, but still…

Comment: The problem is the last comma? or if the get_url return an invalid url?

Comment: If you can't do this in your controller, at least use a custom Twig function to create your json. https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Thanks guys! that makes sense now that I think about it I'll build the object in the model or a service. @Matteo the get_url() is just for example purposes, the problem is the last comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if is the last loop iteration with the standard [cycle twig variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable), as example:

```
{"urls": [
{% for i in objects %}
    "/img/example/'{{i.get_url()}}"{% if not loop.last %}  , {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
]}
```

Check [this](https://twigfiddle.com/f2d0tc) working example

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom twig filter and output it on the page like :

```
{{ objects |obj2Json }}
```

In the filter you could just json_encode the object.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html